# "Обучаем персонал быть приветливыми и дружелюбными" — согласование прилагательных с существительным

Tags: пунктуация, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

> Мы проявляем чуть больше заботы о постояльцах, например, предлагаем завтраки, обучаем персонал быть приветливыми и дружелюбными.

Правильно ли согласованы прилагательные со словом "персонал"? И правильно ли обособлено слово "например"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Мы проявляем чуть больше заботы о постояльцах, например предлагаем завтраки, обучаем персонал быть приветливым и дружелюбным.**

1. При слове *персонал* нет определений, с ним ничего не согласуется. Краткие прилагательные *приветлив* и *дружелюбен* находятся в синтаксической связи с глаголом быть (быть (каким?) приветливым и дружелюбным). Тем не менее должно быть соответствие в числе между персоналом и требуемыми качествами (приветлив и дружелюбен).
2. *Например* — вводное слово. На мой взгляд, здесь действует правило:

> Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота – запятые ставятся перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота. После вводного слова запятая не ставится ([Вводное слово и обособленный оборот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2))